How to set C1-C3 to manual exposure on EOS R7?
There's 3 custom modes on Canon EOS R7, which I've setup for regular 4K, 120fps 1080p, and timelapse, but I cannot find a way to use manual exposure on these modes.
Q How do I use manual exposure on C1, C2, and C3?

To use manual exposure in the C1, C2, & C3 custom modes on most Canon cameras, the mode dial needs to be set to M when the custom profile is "recorded".
There's usually also another menu item that selects whether to always start with the recorded Tv and Av when the mode dial is turned to one of the previously recorded custom modes, or to remember the last Tv and Av settings used when the camera was used in that specific custom mode.
Important Note: I've not used an R7, but I have used a wide variety of other Canon ILCs over the last 30 years.
